# How to combine these two LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I combine these two LINQ statements into one?

```
var Priority = repository.GetMany<Letter>(l => l.UserID == currentUser.ID)
                         .Select(l => l.Priority)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
var User = repository.GetMany<Letter>(l => l.Priority > Priority)
                     .Select(l => l.User)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I need to get Priority of the currentUser and then get the next user that has the next Priority. For example, if the Priority of `currentUser` is 1, I need to get the user with Priority == 2.

Example:

```
letter=new letter { 
    User=Mark, Priority=1
    User=Raha, Priority=2
    User=Searah, Priority=3
}
```

when currentUser is Mark with Priority=1,i need to get user with Priority=2,in this sample Raha!

Comment: Can you give more information about how you want to combine the two? What result do you expect from combined expression?

Comment: Minor note; the "next user" might be unreliable until you add an OrderBy

Comment: No,when i said next user,i mean next user with next Priority!!

Comment: Can you just write an example of how the result could look so that it's a bit more clear?

Comment: i did,i hope that's clear enough.

Comment: What is `GetMany`? That is not a part of standard linq, so it can be hard to combine your statements...

Comment: @ Kobi : It's equivalent to `where(l => l.UserID ==currentUser.ID)`

Comment: So to be clear, what you want is not necessarily a combination of the two queries, but a new one that given a priority P, retrieves the name of a user who has priority = (P+1). Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: If it's equivalent to `Where()`, why use a wrapper?

Comment: @ Kjartan: almost correct!i need to  retrieves the name of a user who has priority = (P+1) and i don't know P,i should get P of currentUser first.

Comment: If you only need the next user, why are there three users in your example?

Comment: @phant0m : forget about that!certainly there's a reason,the question is important here!

Comment: Do you need abstract LINQ implementation, or specific one that will be correctly translated to SQL? I *assume* that you use Entity Framework (from tags), but that's not evident from either your code or your question.

Comment: @ Serg Rogovtsev : I need something to will be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your GetMany are indeed just Where calls, and therefore they returns an IQueryable, the following should do the trick I think:

```
var users = repository
    .GetMany<Letter>(l => l.Priority > (
        repository.GetMany<Letter>(
            l2 => l2.UserID = currentUser.ID
        )
        .Select(l2 => l2.Priority)
        .First()
    )
    .OrderBy(l => l.Priority)
    .Select(l => l.User)
    .Take(1);
```

Your first query is basically just inserted in the second query.